# What am I doing wrong with my Gst pipeline for v4l2 mjpg/yuvy to h264 rtp stream?

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, gstreamer

I am trying to stream webcam video to tcp or rtp, or whatever. The destination part is not what is bothering me, I know that might be erronous, but I have a mind to try some tcp/http and rtsp/rtp stuff to figure out what works best.

I am on a raspberry Pi 4,  4 Gb model

My Webcam supports `YUVY` or `MJPG` output. I have tried to construct a pipeline, like this:

```bsh
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
  ! 'video/x-raw format=mjpg,framerate=(fraction)30/1' \
  ! omxmjpegdec ! omxh264enc \
  ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96 \
  ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

and it throws the following back at me:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not parse caps "video/x-raw\ format=mjpg,framerate=(fraction)30/1"
```

I am at a loss as to what to do, and would really appreciate some help at this point, as I seem to simply be unable to make a pipeline that will take the contents of the webcam and use the hardware h264 encoder.

Answer (score 0):

mjpg is not a valid video/x-raw format. Try "image/jpeg, framerate=30/1" instead of 'video/x-raw format=mjpg,framerate=(fraction)30/1':

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
  ! "image/jpeg, framerate=30/1" \
  ! omxmjpegdec ! omxh264enc \
  ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96 \
  ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

You can probably simplify the pipeline. Perhaps you don't really need the h264 encoding and could use rtpjpegpay instead of rtph264pay.